# How to ignore code during a PHPUnit Test

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am creating unit tests in php.
There is one line in the code under test which generates a random number and assigns it to property of an object. This object is then compared as an assertion.
Because of this, I cannot get the test to pass, so I'm wondering; is there a way to ignore this line with any compiler variable or similar?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better add `test code`

Comment: You should probably extract that line to method and mock it.

Comment: Show the class or method you are testing, and the unit test please!

Comment: If the code's job is to assign a random number to a property, then assert that's what happening. What assertions are you trying to run?

Comment: You can test that that property is of the expected type and within a specific range of values. Don't see any issue why you should not be able to assert that property from your question. Maybe you should add a little more context?

Comment: And if you can not get the test pass and you say the code is right, than the test is unstable. You need to fix the test then (and you've created unstable tests just for the record).

Comment: @Pyton, please write it as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer.